# What is the complexity of calculating frequencies of elements in a collection?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, reduce

Here is the implementation of `frequencies` in `clojure`:

```
(defn frequencies
  "Returns a map from distinct items in coll to the number of times
  they appear."
  [coll]
  (persistent!
   (reduce (fn [counts x]
         (assoc! counts x (inc (get counts x 0))))
           (transient {}) coll)))
```

Is `assoc!` considered a mutation or not?

What is the complexity of `assoc!` inside `frequencies`?

Also it seems that `counts` is accessed twice in each iteration: does it cause a performance penalty?

Answer (score 4):

`assoc!` is mutation of a transient, it is O(log n) amortised I believe. Hence the whole executions of `frequencies` is O(n log n).

`counts` is a locally bound variable, so accessing it twice is no problem.

Here is a functional version of freqencies that doesn't use any multiple state:

```
(defn frequencies-2 [coll]
  (reduce (fn [m v] (assoc m v (inc (get m v 0)))) {} coll))
```

This functional version is also O(n log n), though it will have somewhat more overhead (a higher constant factor) due to creating and discarding more temporary objects.

Comment: `assoc!` and `assoc` are effectively O(1): see my answer below.

Comment: @viebel - sure, log32 n in this case will be small enough that you can consider using it in places where you want an O(1) operation for most practical purposes. However it's still not as fast as many genuine O(1) operations (e.g. a HashMap put) and technically the algorithm still has O(log n) complexity. Hence I think it is a little disingenuous to describe it as O(1).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tree to store the map from elements to frequencies with log(n) complexity (it can be a binary search tree, an AVL, a red-black tree, etc.).
Choose a functional implementation of this tree, i.e. you can't mutate it, but instead `assoc counts x freq` returns a new data structure, sharing in memomry the common parts with `counts`. It's a kind of "copy on write".
Then the performance of computing all frequencies would be O(n log(n)).

Comment: Thanks! I have modified a little bit the question. Have a look!

Answer (score 1):

`assoc!` mutates a transient data and it has much better performance than `assoc`. It is not really a violation of the immutable Clojure's model (see http://clojure.org/transients).

1. `persistent!` and `transient` are O(1)
2. `assoc!` is O(log32 n) which is effectively O(1) as `hash-map` has an upper bound on the size of ~2^32 items this leaves a maximum tree depth of 6

Therefore, the complexity of `frequencies` is linear on the size of `coll`.

Remark: As noticed by @mikera, the complexity of `frequencies` would be linear also with `assoc` but with a higher constant factor.